# Unable to update new database fields in Symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am 3 days old to a Symfony php project. I am unable to save newly created database fields. I need to save a string 'receipt' or 'invoice' on some condition which I have detected already. My codes are following:

```
class ReceiptPage
{
```

....

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="analyzed_invoice_number", type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     */
    private $analyzedInvoiceNumber;
```

setters and getters:

```
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAnalyzedInvoiceNumber()
    {
        return $this->analyzedInvoiceNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $analyzedInvoiceNumber
     */
    public function setAnalyzedInvoiceNumber($analyzedInvoiceNumber)
    {
        $this->analyzedInvoiceNumber = $analyzedInvoiceNumber;
    }
```

even though I am setting the property forcefully before `$em->flush();` it is not being saved.

I am saving the property like this:

```
$receiptPage->setStatus(ReceiptPage::STATUS_FINISHED); // this is working
$receiptPage->setAnalyzedInvoiceNumber('receipt'); // this is not working
$em->flush();
```

Is there anything has a connection with *Doctrine* and *ORM* ? If I set the values to the existing properties forcefully, it is working but the new property is not being saved. 
the db column is **analyzed_invoice_number**.

I have tried a lot from some blogs but failing. 
Can anyone help? The project is also using **Redis** and **Elastic search**
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony Docs for Symfony2.7 state the following on [updating an Object](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine.html#updating-an-object):

> Notice that calling $entityManager->persist($product) isn't necessary. Recall that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the $product object. In this case, since you fetched the $product object from Doctrine, it's already managed.

While not required, try to solve this issue by persisting this object first and flush it afterwards.

Comment: Hi @Moritz Fromm thanks for your help, I tried it but not much help